# Almacenar Servicios WEB (seguridad)

Tags: php, html, webservice, backend, frontend

Buen día a todos.

Tengo una duda muy grande y siendo sincero no la veía venir cuando comence con mi proyecto,

El tema es el siguente, tengo mi pagina web en [www.mipagina.com](http://www.mipagina.com), y mis servicios web en [www.sw.mipagina.com](http://www.sw.mipagina.com) , el tema es que si alguien entra a la pagina de mis SW pues puede acceder a todos los ficheros,

¿Hay alguna forma para que esa URL no sea publica? o cual es la metodologia para seguridad y no puedan acceder a esa URL.

Consumo todos mis SW con JS usando $.ajax y Fetch, y mis SW estan en PHP.

Saludos y buen dia.

Comment: La verdad es que este no es el mejor lugar para hacer esa pregunta, pero igual te diré algo: si publicas en un hosting es con ellos donde tienes que ver el tema de la seguridad de tu página, todos los hosting tienen algunas similitudes, pero en base a lo que pagas ellos te preveeran de algunos u otros servicios, si tu mismo tienes tu host y es ahí en donde tienes alojado el sitio es mas fácil hacer las modificaciones necesarias, ahora si tienes una conexión a internet en la mayoría uno publica su contenido, por lo tanto todo el mundo puede ver tu contenido, de lo contrario no tiene sentido.

Comment: puedes impedir el uso de ficheros mediante apache, con un .HTACCESS definiendo las reglas de dicha carpeta u ficheros

Comment: Justo! cree una capa de seguridad + el .HTACCESS ( que no se me habia ocurrido) funciona perfecto, mis SW siguen corriendo y los ficheros se mantienen privados. GRACIAS!